# Calling Auth.auth().signOut() automatically dismisses the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, uikit

The current view controller gets *dismissed* as soon as I call the `signOut` method by pressing the button. The signing out process however is successful. (I'm using the FirebaseAuth SDK.)

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func logoutPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
    } catch let signOutError as NSError {
        showAlertSaying(
            title: "Fehler beim ausloggen", 
            message: "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten", 
            view: self
        )
        print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to prevent that the view controller gets dismissed?

Comment: what's inside `showAlertSaying`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm calling that function many times in that VC but without dismissing it. And as you may have noticed showAlertSaying only gets triggered if an error occurred but the VC gets dismissed even when there was no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your storyboard button is linked to another action in addition to  this

```
@IBAction func logoutPressed(_ sender: Any) {
```

which has a dismiss / pop action

> This scenario happens when you copy elements in storyboard